# MongoDB Create Resolver - How to return the newly created document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I can't get my create resolver to return the newly created document. It returns null for all values. Here's the code:

RESOLVER

```js
    // SECTION SCHEDULE
    addSchedule: async (
      parent,
      {
        _id,
        streetAddress,
        suite,
        city,
        state,
        zip,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        startTime,
        endTime,
        squareFeet,
        jobDetails,
        numberOfClientEmployees,
        client,
        employees,
        isDisplayable,
      },
      context
    ) => {
      // _id, streetAddress, suite, city, state, zip, startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime, squareFeet, jobDetails, numberOfClientEmployees, client, employees
      // if (context.user) {
      const user = await Schedule.create({
        _id,
        streetAddress,
        suite,
        city,
        state,
        zip,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        startTime,
        endTime,
        squareFeet,
        jobDetails,
        numberOfClientEmployees,
        client,
        employees,
        isDisplayable,
      });
      return (
        {
          _id,
          streetAddress,
          suite,
          city,
          state,
          zip,
          startDate,
          endDate,
          startTime,
          endTime,
          squareFeet,
          jobDetails,
          numberOfClientEmployees,
          client,
          employees,
          isDisplayable,
        },
        {
          new: true,
          returnNewDocument: true,
        }
      );
      // }
      // throw new AuthenticationError("You need to be logged in!");
    },
```

MUTATION

```js
// SECTION SCHEDULE
export const ADD_SCHEDULE = gql`
  mutation AddSchedule(
    $streetAddress: String
    $suite: String
    $city: String
    $state: String
    $zip: String
    $startDate: String
    $endDate: String
    $startTime: String
    $endTime: String
    $squareFeet: String
    $jobDetails: String
    $numberOfClientEmployees: String
    $client: String
    $employees: [String]
    $isDisplayable: Boolean
  ) {
    addSchedule(
      streetAddress: $streetAddress
      suite: $suite
      city: $city
      state: $state
      zip: $zip
      startDate: $startDate
      endDate: $endDate
      startTime: $startTime
      endTime: $endTime
      squareFeet: $squareFeet
      jobDetails: $jobDetails
      numberOfClientEmployees: $numberOfClientEmployees
      employees: $employees
      client: $client
      isDisplayable: $isDisplayable
    ) {
      _id
      streetAddress
      suite
      state
      city
      zip
      startDate
      startTime
      endDate
      endTime
      jobDetails
      numberOfClientEmployees
      squareFeet
      isDisplayable
      client {
        _id
      }
      employees {
        _id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

FRONT-END EXECUTION

```js
  const [mostRecentScheduleAddId, setMostRecentScheduleAddId] = useState(); //fix

  const [addSchedule] = useMutation(ADD_SCHEDULE, {
    onCompleted: (data) => { //fix
      console.log('add schedule = ', data);
      setMostRecentScheduleAddId(data?.addSchedule?._id);
      console.log('most recent id = ', mostRecentScheduleAddId);
    },
    refetchQueries: [
      { query: QUERY_SCHEDULE }, // DocumentNode object parsed with gql
      "getSchedule", // Query name
    ]
  });
```

CONSOLE RESULTS

```
add schedule =  
{addSchedule: {…}}
addSchedule
: 
city
: 
null
client
: 
null
employees
: 
null
endDate
: 
null
endTime
: 
null
isDisplayable
: 
null
jobDetails
: 
null
numberOfClientEmployees
: 
null
squareFeet
: 
null
startDate
: 
null
startTime
: 
null
state
: 
null
streetAddress
: 
null
suite
: 
null
zip
: 
null
__typename
: 
"Schedule"
_id
: 
null
```

I've reviewed the documentation. As noted on the code above I tried new: true since this is the approach on findOneAndUpdate. No luck. Currently I query for the last document created in the DB but I'm not sure that's a long term approach (e.g. if the insert order changes down the road). But maybe it's the solution. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered my post with the solution, and it was well written. I don't see it here now. I can't replicate it exactly, but the solution was to change the return statement in the resolver to read "return user" so as to return the resulting "user" of the Create in the prior block " const user = await Schedule.create...". Thank you so much for catching this error on my part.

RESOLVER

```
    addSchedule: async (
      parent,
      {
        _id,
        streetAddress,
        suite,
        city,
        state,
        zip,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        startTime,
        endTime,
        squareFeet,
        jobDetails,
        numberOfClientEmployees,
        client,
        employees,
        isDisplayable,
      },
      context
    ) => {
      // if (context.user) {)
      const user = await Schedule.create({
        _id,
        streetAddress,
        suite,
        city,
        state,
        zip,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        startTime,
        endTime,
        squareFeet,
        jobDetails,
        numberOfClientEmployees,
        client,
        employees,
        isDisplayable,
      });
      return user
      // }
      // throw new AuthenticationError("You need to be logged in!");
    },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).